# How to simulate paste option 'keep text only' programmatically?

Tags: c#, xml, text, paste

I am writing a program in C# that involves converting .docx files to plain html. I noticed that in some scenarios text in .docx appears different than its plain text representation. However, removing formatting using text editors or `ctrl + shift + v` results in text being pasted *'as it appears'*.
I am looking for a solution to get the text *'as it appears'* as extracting plain text from the .xml results in styling to be ignored.

Appearance in .docx: `- PARAGRAPH`

Plain text behind it: `paRAgrapH`

Ctrl + Shift + V: `- PARAGRAPH`

How is the plain text part of the copied information generated?

Comment: The source application puts it there, or the target application cleans it up. The Clipboard doesn't contain the original file data, it contains what the source application put there in one of the few [predefined formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats) - text, RTF image etc. None of these things is directly related to conversion though. We can't guess what your code is doing. Word's XML schema isn't HTML and the styling doesn't use CSS. Word *generates* HTML when you either save a file to HTML or copy part of a document

Comment: That said, even Word can't create an HTML document that looks exactly like a Word document. The rendering engines are different. Even the notion of *pages* is different - there are no multipage documents in HTML. Some of the styling specified in a Word file can't be done just with HTML in all browsers and CSS and requires Javascript

Comment: I am aware of the different formats that get copied when copying from word. My main concern is if there is a way to recreate the generation that word does when it adds data to your clipboard as *plain text* as it is clear that it is generated  somehow differently than simply taking the characters in the xml.
I mean if the xml would contain "paRAgrapH", word would see the style or some other information associated with the plain text and the result in my clipboard would become - PARAGRAPH.
(Sorry if the context mentioning html is misleading let me know if you think I should edit the question)

Comment: For plain text, read the markup and just keep the text inside the runs and paragraphs. You didn't post any code or even an example of the original text, desired and actual output, so it's impossible to guess what the problem even is, much less what causes it. Does *your* code return text outside runs? Does it miss some runs? Does it convert indentation into spaces or tabs? Or does it *fail* to convert indentation? Did you want to treat soft line breaks differently from paragraphs?

Comment: Instead of working with raw XML you should at least work with the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/word/how-to-open-and-add-text-to-a-word-processing-document?tabs=cs-0%2Ccs-1%2Ccs-2%2Ccs-3%2Ccs), read the entire document and extract the `Text` property of the runs inside a paragraph. That's just a level above working with XML but at least you know which parts go where.